# PHP MySQL time query

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have one question.

So the record in mysql table is like:

```
2014-04-01 15:04:39
```

And all queries are made by url through $_GET in my example fromhour....

This is the input:

```
echo "<input type='time' placeholder='From...'  name='fromhour' id='basicExample' >";
```

This is the function for creating MySQL query.

```
if (isset($data['fromhour']))
{
    $where[] = "RIGHT (calldate, 8) <= '" . $data['fromhour'];
    if ($mode == 'count')
        $used_params[] = 'fromhour=' . $data['fromhour'];
}
```

Now when i put in for example 04:00:00 the url becomes:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php?fromhour=04%3A00%3A00

is there anyway that i can parse or anything so that query in mysql wouldt be 04%3A00%3A00 but 04:00:00?

And this is where I merge the SQL query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test';
    if (count($where) > 0)
        $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: could stand for "Fork"

Comment: Use `urldecode` http://codepad.org/PbocZu5S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use php's [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) before creating the query

```
$nicetime=urldecode('04%3A00%3A00')

> '04:00:00'
```

Comment: It's very strange:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

`Warning
The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.`

Comment: now that you mention it... $_GET variable should be already clean. Weird.